# Transition on div doesn't work in react styled-component

Tags: reactjs, transition, styled-components

I'm new to styled-components; I have a hamburger component and I'm trying to make a transition when the burger menu turns into an X using a styled-component.

I added a `transition: all 0.3s linear` to the div but I just can't figure out what is going wrong with this transition.

```
export default (props) => {
  const StyledBurger = styled.div`
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;

    div {
      transition: all 0.3s linear;
      width: 2rem;
      height: 0.25rem;
      background-color: ${({ open }) => (open ? "#ccc" : "#333")};
      border-radius: 10px;
      transform-origin: 1px;

      &:nth-child(1) {
        transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? "rotate(45deg)" : "rotate(0)")};
      }
      &:nth-child(2) {
        transform: ${({ open }) =>
          open ? "translateX(100%)" : "translateX(0)"};
        opacity: ${({ open }) => (open ? 0 : 1)};
      }
      &:nth-child(3) {
        transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? "rotate(-45deg)" : "rotate(0)")};
      }
    }
  `;

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);


  return (
    <>
      <StyledBurger open={open} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        <div />
        <div />
        <div />
      </StyledBurger>

    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "display: none" in your StyledBurger. That's probably why you don't see children.